# Convert string to date in Crystal Reports

Tags: date, crystal-reports

I need to convert a string value to a date in a crystal report.  As you know Crystal has a handy "in the period of" in the select expert.  However I am unable to use it without converting.  The string is only four characters (example: 0512) I am having trouble using the date value function since there is no day or a full value for the year.   Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This requirement seems typical clarify me one thing in the date format you getting from database what does `0512` means? Is that means month and year or what exactly it represent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just manipulate the string into the proper format and use the CDate function. It doesn't look like the day number matters to you, so set it to the first of the month.

Assuming that 0512 means May 2012 your code should look something like this:

```
CDate('01' + '/' + Left({DateObject},2) + '/' + '20' + Right({DateObject},2))
```

That returns a date of 1/5/12 using your sample value. You can then format it as needed.

Comment: Here is what I used: `local datevar a := CDate('01' + '/' + Left({DateObject},2) + '/' + '20' + Right({DateObject},2));
local numbervar y := Year (a);
local numbervar d := Month (a);
local numbervar m := Day (a);
Date (y, m, d);`

Answer (score 2):

```
cDate(ToText(cDate({?StartDate}),"dd/MM/yyyy")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done since Crystal requires the year to be four digits (YYYY). You will always get a "Bad Date Format" error. See this [article](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic728.html) on the date conversion. You could try and convert it to date on the database end. If your dates are all in the 2000 range, you could get crafty and create a formula that will "build" you a proper date format and then convert it to date.