# Too many arguments have been given to this function

Tags: arguments, coding-style, crystal-reports-2008

I am getting the error, stated in the title, with the following code:

```
ToText (Split ({?CutOffDate},"-") [2]),ToText (Split ({?CutOffDate},"-") [1]))
```

Please help fresh programmer find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is a conversion issue, using the [CDate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412499/6309), as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28474597/6309):

```
ToText(CDate({aString}), "dd-MMM-yy")
```

Don't [forget the `:=` assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549430/6309)

```
EffectiveDateTimeString := ToText(CurrentDate + CurrentTime, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```